# django caching foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating a site where the database model looks similar to this.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = modles.CharField(max_length=30)

class Photos(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

Now I am selecting an element from photos and storing it into cache with `cache.set('object',object,timeout)`. Now I try to access `photos.name` from this cache, no queries are performed. The moment I query for `photos.category` it performs query. Is there any way to prevent this. I only want the id of the category, after getting the id, I can query the category cache to get the element. What is the solution to implement this. Caching this was has improved my benchmarks significantly, I am trying to get more performance out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the ID, you can do `photos.category_id`.

You might also want to explore using `select_related()` to get the related category at the time when you query the original photo.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer myself. My problem was that when I retrieve the object from cache and I query the id it makes another query to the actual database. The solution is simple. Before you save the queryset to cache just query the foreign key. 
like

```
 get photo object from database
 q=photos.category
 cache.set('object',object,timeout)
```

Remember the queryset is lazy. 
If you save this to database, when you access it from cache next time, it will contain the foreign key data also. Hope this helps.